# How to make 3 responsive columns?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make these columns appear 3 columns wide on a desktop screen and 1 column wide on a mobile screen. I'm not sure why but they aren't behaving as I expected. How can I accomplish this?

```html
<section class="pricing-section py-5" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-duration="2000">
  <div class="container single-col-max-width">
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="card col-md-4 col-sm-12 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Basic</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email support</li>
            <li>Help center access</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-4 col-sm-12 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Standard</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email support</li>
            <li>Help center access</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-md-4 col-sm-12 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Premium</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email support</li>
            <li>Help center access</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--//container-->
</section>
```

Comment: You mean the whole width? Remove `.container` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following code in mobile view:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="pricing-section py-5" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-duration="2000">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Basic</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Standard</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Premium</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$500 <small class="text-muted">+</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```